# try to count onclick android

Tags: android, onclick, buttonclick

I need to count clicks and display number of clicks on `textView2` and my code just displays the number 4. I used a while loop to check the number of clicks.

```
public void Clicks(View v){
    final TextView answerLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); //show text from answer variable.
     TextView count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); //display click count.
    String answer = null;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 5){   // I allow user click just 5 time.

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1 :
           answer= "ROCK";
           answerLabel.setText(answer);
           count.setText(String.valueOf(i));
           i++;
        break;
        case R.id.button2 :
         answer = "SCISSOR";
         answerLabel.setText(answer);
         count.setText(String.valueOf(i));
         i++;
         break;
        case R.id.button3 :
        answer = "PAPER";
        answerLabel.setText(answer);
        count.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        i++;
        break;
        }
    }   
}
```

How do I display it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put int i = 0; outside of onClick at class level and start it at 1

```
public int i = 1;
```

then in onClick use an if statement

```
   if(i <= 5)
{
switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1 :
           answer= "ROCK";
           answerLabel.setText(answer);
           count.setText(String.valueOf(i));
           i++;
        break;
        case R.id.button2 :
         answer = "SCISSOR";
         answerLabel.setText(answer);
         count.setText(String.valueOf(i));
         i++;
         break;
        case R.id.button3 :
        answer = "PAPER";
        answerLabel.setText(answer);
        count.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        i++;
        break;
        }
}
```

Comment: glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

change break to continue; because break will stop the loop

but in this case, you are incrementing each time the person clicks.

so you dont need the loop at all.

you need if condition instead! such as if(i<5) and make i the global variable

Comment: @JangJoo  I need to limit click from user and grab value from button to another function , if I want to grab 5 value before do next function 
I should to use "if" or "switch" condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Search for you onCreate() method where your layout is inflated and try this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
int i =0;
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {
            answer= "ROCK";
                            answerLabel.setText(answer);
                            count.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                            i++;
        }
    });
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {
            answer= "SCISSOR";
                            answerLabel.setText(answer);
                            count.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                            i++;
        }
    });
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {
            answer= "PAPER";
                            answerLabel.setText(answer);
                            count.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                            i++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I try to do this but I have no idea how to send "answer" to another function and I think this code can't limit click from user. so can you suggest me ?